# Why won't GetMenuItemInfo work?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to read the label names of menu items in an active application and store them in a `List<String>`.

Unfortunately, `dwTypeData` ALWAYS returns `null`.  Why is this?

```
            List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        IntPtr hMenu = Win32.GetMenu(hWnd);

            if (hMenu.ToInt32() != 0)
            {

                for (int i = Win32.GetMenuItemCount(hMenu); i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        uint MIIM_STRING = 0x00000040;
                        uint MFT_STRING = 0x00000000;
                        uint MIIM_TYPE = 0x00000010;
                        Win32.MENUITEMINFO mif = new Win32.MENUITEMINFO();
                        mif.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32.MENUITEMINFO));
                        mif.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
                        mif.fType = MFT_STRING;
                        mif.cch = 256;
                        mif.dwTypeData = "";
                        Win32.GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, (uint)i, true, ref mif); //To load cch into memory
                        Win32.GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, (uint)i, true, ref mif); //To fill dwTypeData
                        ls.Add(mif.dwTypeData);
                    }
                    catch { }

                }
            }

        return ls;
```

Comment: Do you have any you could recommend? The thing that strikes me about this code and your comment, is my program can successful detect how many items are in the menu, as well as display or remove the menu, so why can't it read the text values from the labels? I'm confused... Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

a) the loop should be `for (int i = Win32.GetMenuItemCount(hMenu) - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

b) before the first call to `GetMenuItemInfo()`, you need to set `mif.dwTypeData` to NULL (zero)

c) before the second call to `GetMenuItemInfo()`, `mif.dwTypeData` should point to a buffer allocated with a size of `mif.cch + 1` -- [see MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Make sure you deallocate the memory afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to perform this action in a different process. When you call `GetMenuItemInfo` you pass the address of a `MENUITEMINFO` struct. But that address is only valid in your process. Because each process has its own private virtual memory space, that pointer that you send has no meaning in the other process.

It's possible that you could use `VirtualAllocEx`, `WriteProcessMemory` and `ReadProcessMemory`  to allocate, write and read an instance of the `MENUITEMINFO` struct in the address space of the other process. That's your only hope of making this mechanism work. There are lots of examples to be found using websearch that illustrate the technique.

However, I would not recommend that you do that. You should use one of the standard automation interfaces to solve your actual problem. For example UIAutomation.

Comment: Are you still looking for answers here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
mif.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
mif.fType = MFT_STRING;
```

with

```
mif.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE;
mif.fType = MIIM_STRING;
```

The [Win32 API MENUITEMINFOA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfoa) documentation states that

> **MFT_STRING** is replaced by **MIIM_STRING**.